# How long does it typically take to edit and finalize a research paper?

Tags: advisor

I have submitted a draft paper (word count is about 11000 words) to my supervisor in Late July 2021. My supervisor has started editing the paper in late September but hasn't finished it yet. Editing about 30% of the paper is still remaining. Is it normal to take this long? I must mention that the field I work on is not the field of expertise of my supervisor.

Edit 1: added word counts in response to answers.

Comment: Are you saying that your supervisor is editing the paper even though you haven't heard back from the journal where you submitted the paper to? Or are you saying that you submitted your draft to your supervisor?

Comment: Regardless, it seems to me like you have major communication issues with your adviser. If you wonder when he will finally be done, or if this is the time frame that things usually take, then these are questions you should be talking about with your adviser!

Comment: Net time, between 1 hour and 1 day. If it takes longer, the draft is far from ready. It looks like your case is at the higher end of that range. Your supervisor probably struggles to find time slots and has to prioritize other duties. You should discuss this with them. Maybe they increase the priority, maybe another co-author is needed.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I have submitted it to my supervisor. Thanks for pointing out that it is not clear.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for giving the estimate. He takes similar time (1-2 months) for other students as well. I guess he has difficulty finding time or motivation.

Comment: "About 30% of the paper is still remaining" - how do you know this? Did you see the edits? If so, the draft must've been in a really rough shape...

Comment: Rather than edit you are speaking about co-writing a paper. It can takes few days or months. At least it looks like given the long interval. Otherwise the supervisor did nothing or very little. This is not a real question.

Comment: Expected time depends on the subject as well as what the purpose of the "editing and finalizing" is. For example, if this is a maths paper with 20 pages of proofs which you want your supervisor to check line-by-line, then it could take months (especially if they haven't seen these proofs before).

Comment: @user1729 right, and I would not call it editing

Comment: @Alchimista I agree, but it can be part of finalizing. However, I put "editing and finalizing" in quotes because, with 30% of the paper unfinished, we are not talking about either "editing" or "finalizing"!

Comment: @Lodinn I think there is some confusion due to the wording used in the question. By 30% remaining, I meant editing 30% is remaining. I have submitted the full paper.

Comment: @Alchimista 30% of the paper is not unfinished, 30% editing is unfinished. I submitted a fully complete paper. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @user1729 The editing process requires changing the English and asking me to change some figures. No proofs.

Comment: No, I get you submitted the full text, was just wondering how do you even estimate these 30%. Your answer to Buffy clarifies that a bit: you're watching updates on the cloud (still, what do these 30% mean? 2 sections finished, 1 untouched?). By the sound of it, this is a rather major edit so spending a few weeks on it if they haven't seen the material before would probably be expected.

Comment: @Lodinn 30% is a rough estimate based on the word counts. Thanks for the alternative perspective. It is possible that I have unrealistic expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time seems long, but probably not unprecedented. There isn't enough information here to make a judgement about the reasons, but if this is normal behavior for them, then it is possible that they are just in over their head - too many students, too varied the topics. The fact that it is outside their normal field of interest is probably responsible for a lot of it. They need to do their own research, perhaps, just to keep up with you.

You don't list a reason for the July - September delay. Vacations? Travel? Other deadlines? Laziness? Incompetence? But you suggest that they have only been working on it for a bit over a month. That is more normal. And you deserve updates during that month.

You don't give the length or difficulty of the paper. If it is just a "draft" then it may be harder for them to manage. If it is in a difficult subject or is pretty rough, then a longer turn-around can be explained.

You don't say how critical the time is. If it is a serious issue then you should expect more from them, otherwise, maybe not.

But, you need to make progress and your supervisor has a responsibility to help. You need to communicate with them, preferably in person, to work out a solution. Bugging them or accusing them is unlikely to get a better result. But you need to talk to them and work out a plan.

One option to suggest is that they give you back the part they have finished so that you can make any necessary updates. You can ask them to send along updates as they have them. You can tell them that you are a bit blocked until you get their feedback.

But, one meeting probably isn't enough. Suggest that you meet every couple of weeks for half an hour to get advice and feedback. They owe you that much. Getting partial updates may be enough to let you keep your momentum.

Comment: "Suggest that you meet every couple of weeks for half an hour to get advice and feedback." That's extremely short meetings. In my experience, biweekly to weekly for one to two hours is optimal when the PhD student is writing a paper.

Comment: Although it is not his area of expertise, he knows exactly what I have done (we met every week to discuss the project while it was going on). Reason for the Jul-Sep delay is other deadlines. The paper is shared on the cloud, so I can see live updates on what he has done and I immediately work on the updates. Length of the paper is ~11000 words (not sure how to quantify difficulty, he knows what has been done). I am completing 7 years, and I can't start postdoc applications unless the papers are at least put up on arxiv. He is well aware of the position I'm in, but doesn't seem to care.

Comment: You can have a section on the CV: Work in Progress. List the project(s) there with titles as available. They don't really need to be public to _start_ the postdoc process. Don't assume more obstacles than you actually have.

Comment: I don't have much else to show for my PhD (apart from the product that I have developed during my PhD). This is the major paper that took about 5 years of work (development of the product + clinical trial). There is another minor paper which he is yet to start editing. Apart from these, I have one paper as a second author in SciRep. Am I correct in assuming that these arxiv papers will significantly increase my chances of getting an interview?

Comment: Perhaps they will, but it probably isn't worth assuming it if the alternative is lost time. Especially a lost year. Write a good CV. The people you want to apply to probably understand the difficulty of research and results in your field.

Comment: I won't be able to write a good CV with what I have (mediocre at best compared with other candidates I have seen.) Can a good research statement add some value to my application?

Comment: Yes, of course, and don't underestimate the impact of a solid "Work in Progress" section. Those who have something going on seem more impressive (to me) than those who are just waiting.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it normal to take this long?

Yes. This is field dependent I suppose, but in general, editing a paper for publication (again, depending on the area) is a very hard work, and your supervisor have only taken about one or two months for editing at this point, which is not only normal, but quite a short period (assuming he/she is doing a serious job of reviwing and rewriting).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the alternative perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell me the word count of your paper?

I used to edit academic papers and our expected turnaround time depends on the word count. If your word count is around 4,000 words, I'd expect it to be edited and returned within about one week. If your word count is 50,000 words, then it will take a fair bit longer.

For a short paper, I'd expect it back within two weeks. After two weeks, you have a right to politely ask the supervisor for some feedback or an update. Please be polite about it though, because your supervisor might be under a lot of stress. A quick coffee catch-up is a good idea.

Comment: Hi, the word count is about 11000 words.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it normal to take this long?

No, this is unusual, and highly problematic. This behavior from your advisor severely cripples your ability to make progress as you are getting blocked on something in your research which should have taken a week or two. If you haven't, you need to be sending reminders to your advisor, at least weekly, e.g.:

> Hey X, Following up on this -- can you give me an expected timeline on when you would be able to edit and finalize our draft manuscript?

In my impression, your supervisor is not doing a good job of supervising you. If they are not malicious, then reminders and direct communication like the above might help. It is likely they are just extremely busy, but that does not excuse ignoring and completely neglecting a PhD student.

Comment: I think that sending reminders weekly, especially in the tone you suggest, is counterproductive. Both in terms of extending the time and in the possible attitude of the supervisor towards the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do not think there is malicious intent. I think it is more of an indifference. I have tried nudging, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The fact that this type of neglectful behavior is the status quo and people are completely OK with it is a huge cultural problem in academia. I get that people are busy, and it's common, but it shouldn't be a hard ask to get a specific timeline on feedback or edits to a paper.

Comment: It actually helps no one to delay on the edits. It does not help the supervisor, as they have to do the work eventually anyway, instead it just creates a snowball effect for them where they in turn delay other responsibilities. It obviously does not help the student. Lose-lose

Comment: @ArkaGhosh FWIW I am not saying your supervisor is malicious, I'm saying this behavior is all-too-common and really should not be tolerated in our culture (unfortunately it is). I don't really have a concrete suggestion if the supervisor refuses to provide a timeline. Perhaps taking matters into your own hands and offering to do the edits yourself

Comment: Also, I fully agree with what @Buffy's answer says.

Comment: @6005 I believe the only way out is "set deadlines and agree on the course of action if they're not met". I know I would easily not even touch some parts of the backlog for months given there are other parts, with deadlines set. I don't know if some supervisors actually refuse to provide them altogether: they surely should realize the student is in the right to demand their interests being considered...

Comment: @6005 Thanks for your comments. I agree with your comment on the neglectful attitude being tolerated. I think the reason is the power asymmetry in the supervisor-student relationship. A supervisor can seriously hurt a student's career choices while a student can do very little. So, the student pretty much has nothing to do other than tolerate.

Comment: @6005 I have done what I could have done by myself. I need his expertise in improving the manuscript. I guess I have nothing to do other than keep nudging and hoping that he finishes it soon.